# 2.7.2 Idle message when logged into CP

Tags: control-panel, login

I've just upgraded from 2.6.1 to 2.7.2 of EE and when I log in I get this message at the bottom of the screen  below the EE copyright message:

```
    You've gone idle, please enter your password to continue
```

If I enter my password I am logged out and when I log back in I see the same message at the bottom of the screen.
Yet I am logged in and can continue working.  Not a show-stopper but it is an indication that something has gone wrong.
Any ideas what is causing this?

Cheers,

Dorothy

Comment: Hi Dorothy, have you tried clearing all the cookies for the domain? An old cookie could still be there from before the update causing havoc.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for taking the time to answer.  I did try that but as you can see, it was a themes folder problem.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted. When you can, mark your answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silly me, I hadn't copyied up my new version of the themes folder.  Hopefully this will be of help to someone else with a short-term memory!

Answer (score 1):

It might be a CSS cache problem.
Is the new version of the file "/themes/cp_themes/default/css/global.css" loaded?
It includes style declaration to hide the issued area.

---

The cause of my problem is that I copied DB from production environment to development one and then updated only development server.
I can see development site at, for example, "https://development.example.com/admin.php", but it keeps production site's setting that the url is "http://production.example.com/".
So, my browser loads CSS files from production site which have not been updated yet.
That's why I asked you to check CSS file cache.

Regards,

IKEDA Tatsunobu

Comment: I see no difference between the global.css files in my 2.5.2 and 2.7.2 installs and I still see the problem.